# Matching "~" at the end of a filename with a python regular expression

Tags: python, regex, tilde

I'm working in a script (Python) to find some files. I compare names of files against a regular expression pattern. Now, I have to find files ending with a "~" (tilde), so I built this regex:

```
if re.match("~$", string_test):
    print "ok!"
```

Well, Python doesn't seem to recognize the regex, I don't know why. I tried the same regex in other languages and it works perfectly, any idea?

PD: I read in a web that I have to insert

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

but doesn't help :( .

Thanks a lot, meanwhile I'm going to keep reading to see if a find something.

Answer (score 10):

[`re.match()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.match) is only successful if the regular expression matches at the beginning of the input string. To search for any substring, use [`re.search()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.search) instead:

```
if re.search("~$", string_test):
    print "ok!"
```

Answer (score 9):

Your regex will only match strings "~" and (believe it or not) "~\n".

You need re.match(r".*~$", whatever) ... that means zero or more of (anything except a newline) followed by a tilde followed by (end-of-string or a newline preceding the end of string).

In the unlikely event that a filename can include a newline, use the re.DOTALL flag and use \Z instead of $.

"worked" in other languages: you must have used a search function.

r at the beginning of a string constant means raw escapes e.g. '\n' is a newline but r'\n' is two characters, a backslash followed by n -- which can also be represented by '\n'. Raw escapes save a lot of `\\` in regexes, one should use r"regex" automatically

BTW: in this case **avoid the regex confusion ... use whatever.endswith('~')**

Comment: thanks it works, one more question, what is the meaning for the initial r that you put in re.match(r".*~$", whatever) i mean the r in
r".*~$" .  thanks for you great help!

Comment: @fkn_man, read about string prefixes here: http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/strings.html

Answer (score 7):

For finding files, use [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) instead,

```
import os
import glob

path = '/path/to/files'
os.chdir(path)
files = glob.glob('./*~')

print files
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct regex and the `glob` solution have already been posted. Another option is to use the `fnmatch` module:

```
import fnmatch
if fnmatch.fnmatch(string_test, "*~"):
    print "ok!"
```

This is a tiny bit easier than using a regex. Note that all methods posted here are essentially equivalent: `fnmatch` is implemented using regular expressions, and `glob` in turn uses `fnmatch`.

Note that only in 2009 a [patch](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/fnmatch.py?r1=33521&r2=74475) was added to `fnmatch` (after six years!) that added support for file names with newlines.

Comment: The correct `str.endswith('~')` solution has also been posted. This is *much* easier to use than `fnmatch`.